# Searching and finding results from a webpage using beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

We have a requirement to scrap the data from google adbar. I'm using python for this but the results are not getting as expected,Can anyone help me with this.

The requirement is to get the results such as product Name, Company name , Their relative position and the Product URL from the webpage.

Using the below script it is giving not 100 % good results,Since i'm new to Python can any pone correct me or give me some recommendations on this?

The Final result should be
product name    URL     Position     Company

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Grab and open URL, create BeatifulSoup object
url = "https://www.google.com/search?&q=iphone+11"
headers={
'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')
#Grab Table of Contents
grab_toc = soup.find('div', {"class":"Yi78Pd"})

#Look for all divs with class: li
ftext = grab_toc.findAll('div', {"class":"mnr-c pla-unit"})
#Look for links
links = grab_toc.findAll('a',href=True)

#Iterate
for everytext in ftext:
    text = ''.join(everytext.findAll(text=True))
    data = text.strip()
    print (data)
    print("\n")

for everylink in links:
    print (everylink['href'])
    print("\n")
```

**With selenium**

```
 from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

# prepare the option for the chrome driver
#webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user_123/downloads/chrome_driver')
options = webdriver.Chrome(Options)
options.add_argument('headless')

# start chrome browser
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get('http://www.google.com/iphone 11')
print(browser.current_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
name_link = soup.find_all('div', class_='mnr-c pla-unit')
link = soup.find_all('href')
for n_link, l in zip(name_link,link):
    print(f'{n_link.text}\n{l.text}')
    print('---------')
```

**Exceptions**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user_123/Documents/selenium_with_beautiful_soup.py", line 6, in <module>
    options = webdriver.Chrome(Options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1436, in _execute_child
    executable = os.fsencode(executable)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 809, in fsencode
    filename = fspath(filename)  # Does type-checking of `filename`.
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not type
```

[image]
[image]
[image: u]

Comment: `requests` does not run `js` code so you will not scrape any dynamic content. you will need to use something that does run the js code, like [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: @Nullman Have tried that but was giving exceptions,Added above code.I'm new to python , Can you please suggest what i need to modify on the above code to get results.

Comment: which exceptions?

Comment: @Nullman Added above exception.Can you suggest what to change to make it run?

Comment: looks like an issue with selenium/chrome webdriver. make sure everything is updated, maybe try another webdriver(not a selenium experts, sorry)

Comment: @Nullman So with beautifulsoup and requests module alone we cannot achieve this right?